# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'ready'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to figure out why I am getting this problem and cannot figure it out.  I am guessing it has to do with the libraries added but I am a newby and have spent like 2 days trying different things.  The problem here is for the function calling the fancybox, but it happens whenever I call the document.ready.

Here is the code:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>  <!-- 1.7.2 -->
<script src="public/scripts/applicat.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!--Add link fancybox-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="public/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#add-iframe").fancybox({
            'hideOnContentClick': true
        });
    });
</script></head>

<section id="top-comments" style="margin-top: 10px">
                <div class="left-side">
                    <p class="top-comment-title">Michigan</p>
                    <div class="top-comment-wrapper">
                        <div class="top-comment-header">
                            <span class="user-name">Andrew P.</span>
                            <div class="fix"></div>
                        </div>
                        <p class="top-comment-content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="right-side">
                    <p class="top-comment-title">Notre Dame</p>
                    <div class="top-comment-wrapper">
                        <div class="top-comment-header dispute-comment">
                            <span class="user-name">Jenny S.</span>
                            <div class="fix"></div>
                        </div>
                        <p class="top-comment-content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="fix"></div>
            </section>

            <!-- Articles -->
            <section id="top-resources" style="display:none; margin-top:10px">
                <a id="add-iframe" href="add-link.html" class="top-add-link">Add Link</a>
                <div class="left-side">
                    <p class="top-comment-title">Michigan</p>
                </div>
                <div class="right-side">
                    <p class="top-comment-title">Notre Dame</p>
                </div>
                <div class="fix"></div>
            </section>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            jQuery().ready(function() { 
                jQuery("#discussion-sections > nav ul").tabs("#discussion-sections > section");
            });
        </script>
```

Thanks for your help!
Luis

Comment: You haven't included jQuery correctly. Triple check the location of jquery.js.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker, I did not?  If I link to http://www.sofiaandluis.com/luis/public/scripts/jquery.min.js I can see the jQuery file.  Is that not it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You load Modernizr right after jQuery library somehow (in applicat.js), so `$` variable gets rewritten. Use jQuery in '[noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)' mode, or use Modernizr to load jQuery as described [here](http://modernizr.com/docs/).

Comment: I added the  $.noConflict(); before I called the ready function at the top and now it tells me that I have an uncaught error. `<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $("#add-iframe").fancybox({
    'hideOnContentClick': true
   });
  });
 </script>`

Comment: Thanks @raina77ow, got it to work by doing the following: `<script type="text/javascript">
  var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($j) {
   $j("#add-iframe").fancybox({
    'hideOnContentClick': true
   });
  });
 </script>`

Answer (score 2):

You didn't reference jQuery successfully.

Check this:

```
alert(typeof $ == "undefined");
alert(typeof jQuery == "undefined");
```

If those are true, jQuery was not loaded to the page.

Change:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

To:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.sofiaandluis.com/luis/public/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I just put those two alerts on the Console and it returned false.  What did I do wrong in how I referenced the jQuery? Thanks!

Comment: this is what I see: http://cl.ly/2H2t0c1n2F1y361Z1X1s  . When I check those alerts on the console I get a False return

Comment: @LuisP. Try removing all external js files, keep only jQuery and your code.